# Complete Circuit - Programatic Button

Tags: pi-4

I have two wires when you touch them together and complete the circuit and then release them, an action happens. The key is touching and then releasing them. If you touch them again and release them the action will happen again. Is there a way to connect these wires to the GPIO pins on an RPi to recreate the same behavior?  I would like to have some software that I can send a signal to the RPi to complete the described action above.  I am calling this a programmatic “button” but I am not sure if that is the correct way of describing what I am trying to do.

EDIT: After testing with my voltmeter, the circuit is 3.5v DC

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor ...You might instead be able to substitute a GPIO for one of the wires (the action is only triggered from one of them) depending on the amount of current required.  Make sure you use a resistor if you do that.

Comment: @goldilocks it’s only a 3.5v circuit, does that change anything?

Comment: voltage != **current**

Comment: you could use a relay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked many times.

You are asking if the Pi GPIO can emulate a contact closure.

This is NOT possible. GPIO can supply low voltage 0/3.3V at low current (<16mA).

What you describe appears to be an electronic touch sensor.
Connecting to a foreign circuit is fraught with difficulties.

There are many possibilities;

1. Use a relay.
2. Use an opto isolator.
3. Design a compatible circuit (which requires knowledge of the electrical characteristics of the device.

Comment: Thank you, I had trouble finding the right keywords when searching. This is what I was looking for!